# Is it possible to restrict access to an asset to logged in users?

Tags: assets, users, permissions

i.e. is there a type of `loginRequired` functionality for assets?

Or even better - can I restrict access to a single group, or a require a certain permission?

In the "permissions" tab for users/groups I can only give access to uploading/deleting assets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two similar plugins that look's like it might do the job (I have tested neither).

- [Internal Assets](https://github.com/tikiatua/internal-assets-plugin)
- [MemberAssets](https://bitbucket.org/jkenters/craft-memberassets/)

Comment: "InternalAssets" builds on "MemberAssets" and has some more features.